# Checking information in a dataset in Python

Tags: python, performance, list, iteration, scapy

I currently have a requirement to make a comparison of strings containing MAC addresses  (eg. "11:22:33:AA:BB:CC" using Python 2.7. At present, I have a preconfigured set containing the MAC address and my script iterates through the set comparing each new MAC address to those in the list. This works great but as the set grows, the script massively slows down. With only 100 or so, you can notice a massive difference.

Does anybody have any advice on speeding up this process? Is storing them in a set the best way to compare or is it better to store them in a CSV / DB for example?

Sample of the code...

```
def Detect(p): 
    stamgmtstypes = (0,2,4)
    if p.haslayer(Dot11):
        if p.type == 0 and p.subtype in stamgmtstypes:
            if p.addr2 not in observedclients: 
                # This is the set with location_mutex: 
                detection = p.addr2 + "\t" + str(datetime.now())
                print type(p.addr2)
                print detection, last_location
                observedclients.append(p.addr2)
```

Comment: Apologies Avasal - I meant 'set' - original post amended. Sorry!

Comment: you can convert list to set, this will eliminate the duplicates .. (delete original comment by mistake)

Comment: Is `observedclients` the one that is supposed be a set? Well, judging from what you show, it is a list, not a set. Sets doesn't have `.append` method. You add to sets with `.add`.

Comment: observedclients is indeed the set (or so I believed). I have it declared as "observedclients = []" at the beginning of my code. This may be where my problem is then? I am now assuming that I should have declared my set as "observed = []" and then "observedclients = set(observed)"?

Comment: Well, `[]` creates a list. You need `set()` to create one. And you add to it with `observedclients.add(p.addr2)`. It might improve performance.

Comment: have you checked list/set.__contains__(element) method,

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to [profile your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045556/how-to-profile-my-code) to understand where exactly the bottleneck is...

Also, as a generic recommendation, consider psyco, although [there are a few times when psyco doesn't help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575385/why-not-always-use-psyco-for-python-code)

Once you find a bottleneck, [cython](http://cython.org/) may be useful, but you need to be sure that you declare all your variables in the cython source.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I assumed that the bottleneck was simply the size of the list of MAC addresses. As said, it works great with only a handful of MAC addresses in but as the list grows in size, this is when the script slows down. I suppose a rule for me to bear in mind - never make assumptions!

Comment: @thefragileomen, how long is your script?

Comment: Mike, it's only around 100 lines long with 5 functions. The function that I think is causing the problems is only a few lines long but it does have a few nested if functions. I've edited my main question with it contained within

Comment: @thefragileomen, it looks like you're using `scapy`, right?  `scapy` is pure python, and gets pretty slow as a result... some other packet-slinging libries (such as [pcs](http://pcs.sourceforge.net/)) offload work with `cython` for you... so this *may* help in your situation... I can't say for sure

Answer (score 0):

Try using `set`. To declare set use `set()`, not `[]` (because the latter declares an empty `list`).

The lookup in the `list` is of `O(n)` complexity. It's what happens in you case when the list grows (the complexity grows with growing of `n` as `O(n)`).

The lookup in the `set` is of `O(1)` complexity on the average.

http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Also, you will need to change some part of your code. There is no `append` method in `set`, so you will need to use something like `observedclients.add(address)`.

Comment: ovgolovin, apologies - error in my original post. I meant 'set' as opposed to 'list'. I'm already using a set and NOT a list but still experiencing the same problem.

Comment: @thefragileomen Very strange, because if the size of the set grows, it shouldn't increase the difficulty of the algorithm (since the complexity is `O(1)` and it's independent of the size of the `set`).

Answer (score 0):

The post mentions "the script iterates through the set comparing each new MAC address to those in the list."

To take full advantage of sets, don't loop over them doing one-by-one comparisons.  Instead use set operations like *union()*, *intersection()*, and *difference()*:

```
s = set(list_of_strings_containing_mac_addresses)
t = set(preconfigured_set_of_mac_addresses)
print s - t, 'addresses in the list but not preconfigured'
```